# Examples table throwing error in Eclipse when parameterising scenario

Tags: eclipse, cucumber, cucumber-java

I am in the process of working through a guide on how to parameterise my test runs with an Examples table however when I write the scenario in Eclipse as the guide states, I get an error against the Examples Table.

I tried refreshing my project or attempting to see if I needed to import anything however there Eclipse does not provide any information beyond the error message. 
"Examples" is set to bold and formatted in the manner of "Scenario Outline:" which suggests Eclipse recognises it for what it is but in spite of this I get an error.

```
    Scenario: Home page default login
        Given User is on landing page
        When User login to application with username <username> and password <password>
        Then Home page is displayed
        And The user is registered 

        Examples:
        |username | password |
        |Leonard  | zxcv     |
        |Lyra     | qwerty   |
```

The error shown against the Examples line is simply;

missing EOF at 'Examples:'

Comment: Try using `Scenario Outline:`

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple, and not "I'm an idiot" although there's an argument for that.

The issue I am experiencing is that I use **Scenario:** as opposed to **Scenario Outline:**

Making that simple change removes the error and allows me to run my test